# Copy Series data from one to another

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

Is there a way to copy data from .Net Chart Series object to empty Series object?
Ive tried to do it with `DataManipulator->CopySeriesValues("Series1", "Series2")` but it trows error:

```
    Series 'Series1' and Series 'Series2' must be aligned to perform the
operation. The series currently have different X values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine here:

```
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];         // source
Series S2 = chart1.Series.Add("S2");  // target, empty! 

chart1.DataManipulator.CopySeriesValues(S1.Name, S2.Name);
```

Your second `Series` was probably **not empty** after all. You can clear it using

```
S2.Points.Clear();
```

Note that this will only copy between two `Series` in the **same** `Chart`.

If you want to copy to **second** `Chart` you can do this:

```
DataSet ds = chart1.DataManipulator.ExportSeriesValues(S1);

Series S2 = chart2.Series[0];
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    S2.Points.AddXY(row.Field<double>(0), row.Field<double>(1));
```

Comment: i tried Points.Clear(); but it still throw error, I'm creating 2 Series, then fill up one of them with values and after try to copy that values to another. My Series type is Spline but i think it doesn't matter here

Comment: Right, the ChartType doesn't matter. If the __target__ Series is indeed empty I don't know what goes wrong.

Comment: It's strange i just swapped  `CopySeriesValues("Series1", "Series2")` and it is working now, i thought "Series1" is destination like in `memcpy`... and documentation said "The following code copies Series1's values from Series2's values." [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456773(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: No, Series2 is the target here. Not exactly a hard rule in .NET but 'copy from A to B' does sound natural, doesn' it?