# Populate line chart with data from datatable in C#

Tags: c#, charts, datatable, linechart

I'm trying with no success to populate a line chart with data from datatable that I created from a SQL query.

Here's my datatable example:

```
Date            Id     Product    Quantity
-----------------------------------------
27/11/2022      12     Audi         3
27/11/2022      12     Ford         7
27/11/2022      12     Mercedes     2
12/10/2022      22     Audi         8
12/10/2022      22     Ford         1
12/10/2022      22     Mercedes     3
08/09/2022      55     Audi         5
08/09/2022      55     Ford         2
08/09/2022      55     Mercedes     4
```

What I'm trying to see in the chart are the 3 distinct dates on the Y axis and the quantity for each product in that date as a point of the product series.

Here an example of my goal:

[image: goal]

Here, what I managed to do for see the distinct dates and product on my chart.

```
var distinct = dt3.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "Product" });

foreach (DataRow item in distinct.Rows)
{                     
    this.chart3.Series.Add(item[0].ToString());                               
}

var distinctdate = dt3.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new[] { "date" });

foreach (DataRow item in distinctdate.Rows)
{
    this.chart3.Series["Petto"].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToString(item["date"]), "1");
}
```

[image: chart]

How can I see the number of each product for the dates?

Comment: _AddXY(Convert.ToString_ Never do this!! Always keep the x-values numeric and add formatting if needed in a series format string.

Comment: @TaW thank you but this not resolve my problem. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: It should. Show the new code! Also: Why do you set Y always to 1 or rather to "1" ?? Note: The y.-values are treted differently: Here the system tried to convert string to numbers; and I can see a blue line at y=1. - The x-values however will instead always be 0 and useless unless you add them as numbers or datetimes!

Comment: @TaW "1" is a sample number that I used. I don't know how to pick from the datatable the values of product for each date. This was my topic

Comment: Ok, for this you may want to have a look at the last line of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507978/copy-series-data-from-one-to-another/36508250#36508250) - Or go for _yourRow.ItemArray[indexOrName]_ - Or got directly for `row[indexOrName]` like shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=net-7.0) The other remarks still apply.

Comment: I still don't understand how to do it. My goal was to group the quantity for each Product and show it in the Y series for each date on the X axys. The post that you linked seems to be different things

Comment: _What I'm trying to see in the chart are the 3 distinct dates on the Y axis and the quantity for each product in that date as a point of the product series._ I guess I don't understand what you want. Nor if you actually want a line chart. If you need groups, maybe you need a selct with a group?. Or you want a stacked chart. Usually one has the quantities in the y-axis and the id as the x-axis.  Or a series for each product?? -  __Can you draw/sketch what you want?__

Comment: @TaW I edited the post with an image of my goal

Comment: Ok, back to square one then: You need to add to data as the correct datatype: x-values as datetimes and y-values best as numbers. I would add two lines for create those variables so you can easily test them  and `...Points.AddXY(aDate, aNumver)`